# Simple Java Script function

Tags: javascript, php

I have this Java Script function this work great but i want if i have more then 6 days left, 00:00:00. Then 'Text' and only time(00:00:00)

```
<?php echo "<script type='text/javascript'> $(function() {
    var endDate = '". date('Y-m-d', strtotime( $dbDate[0] )) ."';
    $('.countdown').countdown({ date: endDate });
}); </script>";?>
```

But i need

```
If($(function)>6 days left, 00:00:00){

<?php echo"nice work";

<?php echo "<script type='text/javascript'> $(function() {
    var endDate = '". date('Y-m-d'-'Y-m', strtotime( $dbDate[0] )) ."';
    $('.countdown').countdown({ date: endDate });
}); </script>";?>
```

but this didn't work

echo nice work and
only (hour min and sec) without m and Y

Example

Disply output(Nice work, 23:21:20)

```
}else{
```

Disply output(5 Days left, 21:23:56)

```
}
```

Comment: Okay simply way is if(more the 6 days, function - 144h) as output this where enough..

Comment: of if more the 6 days disply output only time without yy-dd.             only 23:31:25